# Como criar uma query dinâmica com Left Join?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Como posso fazer para deixar essa *query* dinâmica , ela já está funcionando só que ela só lista um semestre de cada ano e queria que ela  listasse dois, tipo quando seleciono o primeiro ela lista o primeiro e quando solicito o segundo ela lista o segundo.

```
public function RetornaIndoperacionais($ano){

    if($ano == "2016"){
        $_base = "pla_est_2016";  
    }else{
      $_base = "pla_est"; 
    }


    $Query = ("SELECT i.codiniciativa,
    te.nome as nome_tema,
    te.codtemaestrategico as cod_te,
    p.observacoes as per_obs,
    te.sequencia as tem_sequencia,
    p.sigla as per_sigla,
    p.nome as nome_perspectiva,
    p.codperspectiva as cod_perspectiva,
    o.sequencia as sequencia_obj,
    o.codobjetivo as cod_obj,
    o.nome as nome_obj,concat(p.sigla, ' ', te.sequencia,
    '.', o.sequencia, '.',i.sequencia) as codigo,i.nome as nom_iniciativa,
    i.sequencia as iniciativa_sequencia,
    i.metas,i.responsavel,i.indicadores,
    (SELECT a.percentual FROM $_base.avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) = 2016 AND month(a.data) = 1 ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1),
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM $_base.avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) <= 2016 AND month(a.data) < 1 AND curdate() >= '2016-01-01' ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1), 0)) as '01',
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM $_base.avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) = 2016 AND month(a.data) = 2 ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1),
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM $_base.avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) <= 2016 AND month(a.data) < 2 AND curdate() >= '2016-02-01' ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1), 0)) as '02',
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM $_base.avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) = 2016 AND month(a.data) = 3 ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1),
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM $_base.avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) <= 2016 AND month(a.data) < 3 AND curdate() >= '2016-03-01' ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1), 0)) as '03',
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM $_base.avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) = 2016 AND month(a.data) = 4 ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1),
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM $_base.avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) <= 2016 AND month(a.data) < 4 AND curdate() >= '2016-04-01' ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1), 0)) as '04',
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM $_base.avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) = 2016 AND month(a.data) = 5 ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1),
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM $_base.avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) <= 2016 AND month(a.data) < 5 AND curdate() >= '2016-05-01' ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1), 0)) as '05',
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM $_base.avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) = 2016 AND month(a.data) = 6 ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1),
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM $_base.avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) <= 2016 AND month(a.data) < 6 AND curdate() >= '2016-06-01' ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1), 0)) as '06' 
    FROM $_base.perspectivas p 
    LEFT JOIN $_base.temasestrategicos te ON p.codperspectiva = te.codperspectiva 
    LEFT JOIN $_base.objetivos o ON te.codtemaestrategico = o.codtemaestrategico 
    LEFT JOIN $_base.iniciativas i ON o.codobjetivo = i.codobjetivo 
    WHERE p.codperspectiva = '5' AND p.status = 'A' AND te.status = 'A' AND o.status = 'A' AND i.status = 'A'ORDER BY p.sequencia ASC,te.sequencia ASC,
    o.sequencia ASC,CAST(i.sequencia AS DECIMAL) ASC" );


    //echo "</pre>"; print_r($Query); exit;
    //while ($_indoperacionais = mysql_fecth_array($Query));

    try {
          $this->search = $this->MySql->prepare($Query);
          //$this->search->bindParam(":nome", $this->indoperacionais);
          $this->search->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
          die($e->getMessage());
    }

    $_result = $this->search->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $_result;
```

E esse é o código em PHP para entender como quero que funcione o chamado.

```
/* codigo para gerar os paramentros  */
    $ano  = $_POST["ano"];
    $_perspectiva = $_POST["perspectiva"];

    //echo "<pre>"; print_r ($_POST);exit;
    if ($_POST["semestre"] == "primeiro") {
        $_parametros = array (
        "ano" => $ano,
        "mes1" => 1, "mes2" => 2, "mes3" => 3,
        "mes4" => 4, "mes5" => 5, "mes6" => 6,
        "nomeMes1" => "Janeiro", "nomeMes2" => "Fervereiro", "nomeMes3" => "Março",
        "nomeMes4" => "Abril", "nomeMes5" => "Maio", "nomeMes6" => "Junho",
        "perspectiva" => $_perspectiva);
    }else if ($_POST["semestre"] == "segundo") {
        $_parametros = array (
        "ano" => $ano,
        "mes1" => 7, "mes2" => 8, "mes3" => 9,
        "mes4" => 10, "mes5" => 11, "mes6" => 12,
        "nomeMes1" => "Julho", "nomeMes2" => "Agosto", "nomeMes3" => "Setembro",
        "nomeMes4" => "Outubro", "nomeMes5" => "Novembro", "nomeMes6" => "Dezembro",
        "perspectiva" => $_perspectiva);
    }else {
        $error = "ERRO";
    }

    //echo "<pre>"; print_r ($_parametros);exit;
    //Instanciando a classe
    $_model = new model_Indoperacionais();
    $_indoperacionais = $_model->RetornaIndoperacionais($ano,$_parametros);
```

Comment: Allan, pode inserir o início do código ? tem uma variável perdida no meio da sua query.

Comment: Removi as tags de PHP pois a linguagem é irrelevante para sua dúvida.

Comment: @gmsantos a tag [php] será mesmo irrelevante?

Comment: @gmsantos ai está os códigos , tem como verificar para mim ?

Comment: @ramaral não vejo onde o PHP é relevante na questão. O problema ao meu ver é a construção da query, com esse monte de subquery com valores chapados.

Comment: @allanaraujo a melhor abordagem é refazer essa query monstruosa ai. Quando tiver mais tranquilo revisito a pergunta e elaboro uma resposta.

Comment: @gmsantos A forma de parametrizar e de atribuir os valores depende da linguagem utilizada, se fosse em C# eu saberia responder, em PHP não.

Comment: @ramaral a unica coisa que quero é deixar o WHERE p.codperspectiva = '5' que fique no modo dinâmico , tipo quando selecionar uma das 8 perspectiva ela selecione de forma automatica no WHERE p.codperspectiva = '' –

Comment: O que tem de fazer é substituir esse 5 por uma variável ou *placeholder* e depois substituir pelo valor a usar antes de "executar" a *query*. Como isso pode ser feito em PHP não sei. Sugiro que edite a pergunta e use uma query simples como exemplo. Todo esse código e o tamanho da *query* que usou podem estar a dificultar uma resposta.

Comment: @gmsantos quero é deixar o WHERE p.codperspectiva = '5' que fique no modo dinâmico , tipo quando selecionar uma das 8 perspectiva ela selecione de forma automatica no WHERE p.codperspectiva = ''